# Create new annotation in Allure report, e.g. @Release with priority higher than @Feature

Tags: allure

How to create new annotation in Allure report, e.g. @Release with priority higher than @Feature. Or @SubFeature that would be displayed inside @Feature but above @Story in the report?

It is fairly easy to create new annotation as in ru.yandex.qatools.allure.annotations package, the challenge is how to make Allure read them and display in the report properly.

I am using Java/TestNG framework.

Any suggestions welcome !!!

Answer (score 1):

Allure 2 has support for up to 3 levels of grouping for Behaviors tab (Epic -> Feature -> Story). So you can simply use `@Epic` annotation as a first level group. The following test

```
import io.qameta.allure.Epic;
import io.qameta.allure.Feature;
import io.qameta.allure.Story;

@Epic("Allure 2 Features")
@Feature("Support for BDD annotations")
@Story("Epic annotation support")
void shouldSupportEpicAnnotations() {
    //do something
}
```

will be displayed in the report like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I have tried that. Therefore, the reason I am asking is that qameta only allows 3 levels of nesting, same as yandex version. In my project I have a need for more complex nesting of at least 4-5 levels.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already migrated to Allure 2, you may want to check official docs - [plugins system](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_allure_plugins_system) section. It's a good way to start with any customization.